# Python - tkinter askopenfilename function somehow stays active while selecting the file "directly" doesn't

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm not a programmer so admittingly my title might be a bit off.

I have a program where I select an IFC-file (used in the construction industry, which contains data about the geometry and data connected to the objects in the 3D drawing) and then a dialog opens where I can add a GUID (an identifier) and search for all the information related to that object in the IFC-file, which I then print in the command prompt.

A minor issue which annoys me a bit is that the when is select the file in a more flexible way, using askopenfilename, the function seems to stay active or in a loop after I close the later opening dialog, so that I have to end the process using CTRL+C.

I post the entire code as I don't know if there is something else which causes it:

```
#imports to search for files
import os

# imports tkinter for selection purposes, so that one can select the files instead of reading in them automaticall from a directory
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

#importing the counter to counte the occurences in a list
from collections import Counter

#importing regex functionality to check values
import re

#this is the numbering, for example #433, #4781 etc, that we either want to look for or change - now it looks for up to a number of length 7
regexIFCnumbers = '#\d{1,7}'


tk.Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
file1 = askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd()) # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file - this in the current directory where we'll start looking

file1Name = (os.path.basename(file1)) #only the file's name
    
#read files
def readFile(file):
    x = []
    f = open(file, 'r') 
    x = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return(x)

x1 = readFile(file1)

#checks the GUIDs
def checkGUID(GUID, IFC):
    A = []
    for row in IFC:
        if GUID in row:
            #print(re.findall(regexIFCnumbers, row))
            
            A.extend(re.findall(regexIFCnumbers, row))
            return(A)

#the numbering is not perfectly ordered and varies in some places, so need to index it all to find the correct lines
def indexIFC(IFC):
    A = []
    for index, row in enumerate(IFC):
        if re.findall('^#', row): #starts with a hash #
            B = re.findall(r'\#\w+', row)[0]
            A.append([B, index])
            
    return(A)


def recurseThrough(inputList, IFC, checkedList, fullList, indexednumbersList):
    for item in inputList:
        for hashvalueList in indexednumbersList:
            if item == hashvalueList[0]:
                positionInIFC = hashvalueList[1]

        if re.search('^'+item, IFC[positionInIFC]) and item not in checkedList: #if the row begins with the number item in the list
            checkedList.append(item)
            fullList.append(IFC[positionInIFC])
            recurseThrough(re.findall(regexIFCnumbers, IFC[positionInIFC])[1:], IFC, checkedList, fullList, indexednumbersList) #recurses through the next list
    return(fullList)
    

from os import system, name
 
def clear():
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')

def runTheGUIDCheck(setValue):
    inputValue = str(setValue)
    print(inputValue)
    clear()
    
    try:
        B1 = checkGUID(inputValue, x1) #This returns a list with for example [#122, #5, #7889]

        checkedList = [] #the list of already checked items
        fullList = []

        indexedIFClist1 = indexIFC(x1)

        #run the function with the initial input, sending in empty array as well as they should be empty/none at the start
        outList1 = recurseThrough(B1, x1, [], [], indexedIFClist1)

        for index, item in enumerate(outList1):
            print(index, item.strip())
        
        return None
    
    except:
        print("inserted GUID not found or didn't work")
        

        
#dialog
dialog = tk.Tk()

dialog.geometry('500x200')

t1 = tk.Label(dialog, text = 'Check GUID')
t1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'w')

testGUIDAttributes = tk.Entry(dialog, width = 40)
testGUIDAttributes.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 50)

button = tk.Button(dialog, text='Run GUID', command = lambda: runTheGUIDCheck(testGUIDAttributes.get()))
button.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = 'w')

dialog.mainloop()
```

If I select the file directly like this...

```
file1 = 'thefile.ifc'
```

instead of with the above this...

```
tk.Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
file1 = askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd()) # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file - this in the current directory where we'll start looking
```

then this issue doesn't come up and the command prompt will accept new commands after I close the dialog which is "created" at the end.

Comment: Since you have created two instances of `Tk()`: one in the line `tk.Tk().withdraw()` and one in the line `dialog = tk.Tk()`, so the line `dialog.mainloop()` will not return until both windows are closed.  However you cannot close the *withdrawn* window because it is invisible.

Comment: Is there something I could do to work around this so that the process works like I want, but without the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have created two instances of `Tk()`: one in the line `tk.Tk().withdraw()` and one in the line `dialog = tk.Tk()`, so the line `dialog.mainloop()` will not return until both windows are closed. However you cannot close the *withdrawn window* because it is invisible.

You should create only one instance of `Tk()`, hide it and then show the file dialog.  Then show it back and proceed as normal:

```py
...
# create the main window and hide it initially
dialog = tk.Tk()
dialog.withdraw()
file1 = askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd()) # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file - this in the current directory where we'll start looking
...
# show back the main window
dialog.deiconify()
dialog.geometry('500x200')
...
dialog.mainloop()
```